# Is there a name for this type of logical fallacy?

Tags: logic, soft-question, education

Consider a statement of the form: $A$ implies $B$, where $A$ and $B$ are true, but $B$ is not implied by $A$.

**Example:** As $3$ is odd, $3$ is prime.

In this case, it is true that $3$ is odd, and that $3$ is prime, but the implication is false. If $9$ had been used instead of $3$, the first statement would be true, but the second wouldn't, in which case it is clear that the implication is false.

> Is there a name for this sort of logical fallacy?

Comment: Note that technically, the implication "If $3$ is odd, then $3$ is prime" is true, since the implication is logically equivalent to "Either $3$ is even or $3$ is prime or both." That is, $A \to B$ is logically equivalent to $\neg A \lor B$. Keep in mind that implication is not the same as **causation**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that would just be a [non sequitur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_sequitur_%28logic%29) ("it does not follow"), which doubles as a catch-all term for all invalid arguments.

From Wiki:

> Non sequitur (Latin for "it does not follow"), in formal logic, is an argument in which its conclusion does not follow from its premises. In a non sequitur, the conclusion could be either true or false, but the argument is fallacious because there is a disconnection between the premise and the conclusion. All invalid arguments are special cases of non sequitur.

In your case your premise and conclusion happen to be true, but B does not follow since the implication is broken.

Answer (score 6):

The implication is true. A related sentence, "$\forall n$ if $n$ is odd then $n$ is prime" happens to be false.

Answer (score 2):

**Affirming the consequent**

This fallacy takes the following form:
Premise 1:If A, then B.
Premise 2:B.
Conclusion:Therefore, A.
Argument: "Those who practiced authorized plural marriage had multiple sexual partners. John C. Bennett had multiple sexual partners. Therefore, Bennett practiced authorized plural marriage."

Rebuttal: A implies B, but B does not imply A--i.e., authorized plural marriages had multiple partners, but all those with multiple partners were not practicing authorized plural marriage.

Answer (score 1):

If $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are statements about $x$, what happens is that $\exists x_0$ such that $P(x_0)$ and $Q(x_0)$ are true, then you are concluding that $\forall x$, $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are true, which is not necesssarily a valid conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it is called [affirming the consequent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirming_the_consequent).  It is also referred to as a converse error or the fallacy of the converse.

Comment: I would appreciate it if whoever downvoted me would explain why.

Comment: @rank thank you. My response would be that I was responding to the deduction that (I thought) OP meant to express. That is, one would be **affirming the consequent** in deducing that $3$ is prime from $\forall n\geq3:n$ is prime $\implies n$ is odd.

Answer (score 0):

This is not strictly a fallacy; this is a result from the truth-table definition of implication, in which a statement with a true conclusion is necessarily given the truth-value true, i.e., for any formula $A\rightarrow B$ , if B is given the truth-value T, then, by the truth-table definition of $ \rightarrow $, it follows that $A\rightarrow B$  is true. The only invalid statement of this sort is a statement of the sort
$A\rightarrow B$ in which A is true and B is false; this is the essence of what logic is about; we want to avoid starting with a true statement, arguing correctly, and ending up with a false statement; logic is largely designed to avoid this, as correct reasoning is that which preserves true premises, or sends true premises to true premises.

Answer (score 0):

Others have said this is not a fallacy, and that is true in the logics we are used to using in mathematics, but perhaps not in the logics used in natural language or, say, the law.  For example, [Relevance Logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relevance_logic) is designed to disallow this sort of thing.